# Canvas Scaling Coordinates

Tags: android, canvas, coordinates, scale, rect

How do i get the coordinates of a shape after scaling the canvas?
For example the canvas includes some Rectangles. Then the user zooms in. How do i get the new coordinates?

Do i need a matrix? Im using GestureDetector and everything works fine. if the user moves the view also the canvas moves. I mean i see the new position but i dont have access to the coordinates.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mFocusX, mFocusY);
        canvas.translate(mFocusX + mPosX, mFocusY + mPosY);

        drawLines(canvas);

        for(TextRect r : rectList){
            canvas.drawRect(r.getRect(), blue);
            white.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXTSIZE + r.textSize);
            canvas.drawText(r.getRectText(), r.getRect().left + r.xStart, r.getRect().top + 32, white);
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: yes `Matrix` is your best friend